# Is there a way to shorten this insetion sort

Tags: python, insertion-sort

I have two lists I want to merge into one like so:

```
list_0=[[5], [4], [4], [1], [0], [7], [8], [3], [0]]
list_1=[[0], [9], [6], [4], [5], [9], [5], [9], [3]]
mine_position=[[5], [0], [4], [9], [4], [6], [1], [4], [0], [5], [7], [9], [8], [5], [3], [9], [0], [3]]
```

The code I have for merging them is:

```
for i in row:
    mine_position.append(i)

mine_position.insert(1, list_1[0])
mine_position.insert(3, list_1[1])
mine_position.insert(5, list_1[2])
mine_position.insert(7, list_1[3])
mine_position.insert(9, list_1[4])
mine_position.insert(11, list_1[5])
mine_position.insert(13, list_1[6])
mine_position.insert(15, list_1[7])
mine_position.insert(17, list_1[8])
```

I want to shorten it so that the second part can be cleaner, but I can't seem to find a method that works.

Comment: Are the lists guaranteed to have the same length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just zip them together. No loops needed.

```py
list_0=[[5], [4], [4], [1], [0], [7], [8], [3], [0]]
list_1=[[0], [9], [6], [4], [5], [9], [5], [9], [3]]
mine_position = list(zip(list_0, list_1))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can see that your merged list's elements at even indices consists of elements from `list_0` and the odd indices consists of elements from `list_1`. The below code snippet can be used to generate the merged list.

**Code Snippet:**

```
# Original Lists
list_0=[[5], [4], [4], [1], [0], [7], [8], [3], [0]]
list_1=[[0], [9], [6], [4], [5], [9], [5], [9], [3]]

# Merged List
result = []

total_elements = len(list_0) + len(list_1)

# Indices of respective lists
list0_idx = list1_idx = 0

for i in range(total_elements):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        result.append(list_0[list0_idx])
        list0_idx += 1
    else:
        result.append(list_1[list1_idx])
        list1_idx += 1

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
list_0=[[5], [4], [4], [1], [0], [7], [8], [3], [0]]
list_1=[[0], [9], [6], [4], [5], [9], [5], [9], [3]]

merged_list = []

for i in range(0, len(list_0)):
    merged_list.append(list_0[i])
    merged_list.append(list_1[i])

print(merged_list)
```

It shows this.

```
[[5], [0], [4], [9], [4], [6], [1], [4], [0], [5], [7], [9], [8], [5], [3], [9], [0], [3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a new variable and assign it as list_0. We do this so that list_0 is not altered. Then use a loop and insert the element of list_1 every 2 elements.

```
list_0=[[5], [4], [4], [1], [0], [7], [8], [3], [0]]
list_1=[[0], [9], [6], [4], [5], [9], [5], [9], [3]]
merged_list = list_0

idx = 1
for j in list_1:
  merged_list.insert(idx,j)
  idx += 2

print(merged_list)

#Result: [[5], [0], [4], [9], [4], [6], [1], [4], [0], [5], [7], [9], [8], [5], [3], [9], [0], [3]]
```

NOTE the reason we increment it by 2, is because at the start of the iteration, a  new element will be added into the merged_list.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```py
[item for t in [(list_0[i], list_1[i]) for i in range(len(list_0))] for item in t]
```